# How to create radio button as buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, radio-button

How to create regular radio buttons to like normal buttons styled with css?

Here are my radio buttons:

```
<div class="radio-toolbar">

    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radios" value="all" checked>
    <label for="radio1">Radio1</label>

    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radios"value="false">
    <label for="radio2">Radio2</label>

    <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radios" value="true">
    <label for="radio3">Radio3</label>
</div>
```

And my css:

```
.radio-toolbar {width:410px;}

.radio-toolbar input[type="radio"] {
        display:none;
}

.radio-toolbar label {
        display:inline-block;
        background:#FFF;
        font-family:"Arial Black", sans-serif;
        font-size:12px;
        color:#666666;
        width:106px;
        padding-left:4px;
}

.radio-toolbar [type="radio"]:checked + label {
        background:url("../images/radiochecked.png") no-repeat;
        color:#FFF;
}
.radio1 [type="radio"]:checked + label {
        background:url("../images/radio1.png") no-repeat;
        color:#FFF;
}
.radio2 input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
        background:url("../images/radio2.png") no-repeat;
        color:#FFF;
}



.radio-toolbar label:hover {background-color:#bbb;
background:url("../images/radiohover.png") no-repeat;
color:#FFF;
}
.radio2 label:hover {background-color:#bbb;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. You want styled buttons or styled radio buttons?

Comment: And how exactly will you represent "checked" button? We need more details, screenshots will also help.

Comment: Make radio buttons as clickable buttons

Comment: Why not just use ... clickable buttons. What does the radio get you that can't be achieved otherwise?

Comment: I don't understand. What is wrong with the solution you're currently using?

Comment: @Joel I am trying to make a search field with radio buttons that determinate what table it should search in

Comment: @Rails beginner - I get that, but what does the radio control give you in that context that you can't achieve with the button control itself? It's a much simpler task to add a global javascript variable that acts as a toggle for each button than to change the behavior of a dom element.

Comment: @Joel Can you show an example how to do so? I am not an expert in javascript

Comment: You might consider looking at this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482584/html-make-regular-buttons-act-like-a-group-of-radio-buttons/7482820#7482820

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It involves hiding the radio button element and putting in a different element instead (at runtime, to maintain backward compatibility with non-JS-enabled browsers), then echoing changes to the new element to the hidden radio button's state.

As you're already using jQuery, you might consider jQuery UI, which has [exactly this functionality](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#radio).